AZDO API - Get Pull Request for Builds
I am stumped as to how to get the PR relating to each build.
This is pretty critical stuff, as we need to know who approved each build (PR Approvals).
Have pulled the build data (https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{acc}/_apis/build/builds/{bid}?api-version=7.1)
.. but nothing in there that's obvious to me :(
Also done a lot of googling, maybe I'm not searching for the right terms ?
One post mentioned that there was a parameter object on the build output with the PR id, but that was back on v5 of the API and does not appear for me now in v7.
Appreciate any wisdom.

From this comment one may use .triggerInfo['pr.number'] for getting PR which caused the build.
Also there is system.pullRequest.pullRequestId system variable:

System.PullRequest.PullRequestId - The ID of the pull request that caused this build.

When i tried to do a call for a build created by a PR:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/build/builds/123?api-version=7.1

indeed, i got pr.number in the output, and System.PullRequest.PullRequestId in the .parameters string:
{
  ...
  "triggerInfo": { "pr.number": "123", "pr.isFork": "False" },
  "reason": "pullRequest",
  "parameters": "{\"system.pullRequest.pullRequestId\":\"123\",\"system.pullRequest.sourceBranch\":\"refs/heads/AddTerms&Conditions\",   ...",
}

Then, knowing the PR's ID, one may get info about PR, which includes the PR's author, like:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/git/pullrequests/123?api-version=7.1

with the output like:
{
  ...
  "pullRequestId": 123,
  "createdBy": {
    ...
    "displayName": "**** *****",
    "uniqueName": "****.*****@gmail.com",
  }
}


Unfortunately I get {"reason": "batchedCI","triggerInfo": {}.....}
Obviously something missing in my understanding of how I create a PR in the UI, when I complete the PR my Pipeline runs .....yet that is not the 'reason'

@SimonB, would "sourceBranch" be available then? In my case it was "sourceBranch": "refs/pull/123/merge" - which contains PR id in terms of git ref.
